# Python to convert lines in an image to multilinestring

Tags: python, mask, geopandas, rasterio, multilinestring

I have .png files that look something like this:

[image]

I know the x-y coordinates for the corners, so I can place it in a map (each .png normally covers an area of 50x25 meters, so it’s fairly accurate)

I would like to create multilinestring objects from the black lines in the .png

What is the process / steps needed to do it? As a newbie I am struggling to even find what I need to search for.

I use geopandas and shapely with confidence, and I am now reading about rasterio, how to raster an image, apply a mask, vectorize it… I am not sure that will do it. What do I need to look for?

Comment: have you checked out [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/)?

Comment: you might also check out [`rasterio.features`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.dataset_features)